# valgrind finding leaks that are hard to find

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind, destructor

This is part of a program.  When i compile it with g++, it compiles and works fine, but valgrind says that there are definitely lost: 256 bytes in 8 blocks in the leak summary. I narrowed dow the part where the memory leak happens. I tried different things to fix it but valgrind keep finding  ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0). the main leak is happening when the buildTree function is called. how can i fix it?

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int ARRAYSIZE = 100;

class NodeData {
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream &, const NodeData &);
public:
        NodeData();          // default constructor, data is set to an empty string
        ~NodeData();
        NodeData(const string &);      // data is set equal to parameter
        NodeData(const NodeData &);  
        bool setData(istream&);

        bool operator==(const NodeData &) const;
        bool operator!=(const NodeData &) const;
        bool operator<(const NodeData &) const;
        bool operator>(const NodeData &) const;
private:
        string data;
};

NodeData::NodeData() { data = ""; }                         // default

NodeData::~NodeData() { }            // needed so strings are deleted properly

NodeData::NodeData(const NodeData& nd) { data = nd.data; }  // copy

NodeData::NodeData(const string& s) { data = s; }

bool NodeData::operator==(const NodeData& rhs) const {
        return data == rhs.data;
}

bool NodeData::operator!=(const NodeData& rhs) const {
        return data != rhs.data;
}

//------------------------ operator<,>,<=,>= ---------------------------------
bool NodeData::operator<(const NodeData& rhs) const {
        return data < rhs.data;
}

bool NodeData::operator>(const NodeData& rhs) const {
        return data > rhs.data;
}

bool NodeData::setData(istream& infile) {
        getline(infile, data);
        return !infile.eof();       // eof function is true when eof char is read
}

//-------------------------- operator<< --------------------------------------
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const NodeData& nd) {
        output << nd.data;
        return output;
}

class BinTree
{
  public:
        BinTree();                      // default constructor
        BinTree(const BinTree&);                // copy constructor
        ~BinTree();  
    void makeEmpty();
    bool insert(NodeData*);
  private:
        struct Node
        {
                NodeData* data;         // pointer to data object
                Node* left;             // left subtree pointer
                Node* right;            // right subtree pointer
        };
        Node* root;                     // root of the tree
        void makeEmptyHelper(Node*&);
        bool insertHelper(Node*&, NodeData*);
};


BinTree::BinTree()
{       
        root = NULL;
}

BinTree::BinTree(const BinTree& bt)
{       
        this->root = NULL;
        *this = bt;
}

BinTree::~BinTree()
{       
        makeEmpty();
}

void BinTree::makeEmpty()
{       
        makeEmptyHelper(root);
}

void BinTree::makeEmptyHelper(Node*& current)
{       
        if (current != NULL)
        {     
                if (current->data != NULL)
                {       
                        delete current->data;
                        current->data = NULL;
                }
                makeEmptyHelper(current->left);
                makeEmptyHelper(current->right);
                delete current;
                current = NULL;
        }
        delete current;
}

bool BinTree::insert(NodeData* insertion)
{
        return insertHelper(root, insertion);
}

bool BinTree::insertHelper(Node*& current, NodeData* insertion)
{
        if (current == NULL)
        {
                current = new Node;
                current->data = insertion;
                current->left = NULL;
                current->right = NULL;
                //delete insertion;
        }
        else if (*insertion < *current->data)
        {
                insertHelper(current->left, insertion);
        }
        else if (*insertion > *current->data)
        {
                insertHelper(current->right, insertion);
        }
        else
        {
                return false;
        }
        return true;
}

void buildTree(BinTree&, ifstream&);

int main()
{       
        ifstream infile("data2.txt");
        if (!infile)
        {       
                cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
                return 1;
        }

        BinTree T;
        cout << "initial data:" << endl << " ";
        buildTree(T, infile);
        cout << endl;

        NodeData* p;    // pointer of retrieved object
        bool found;     // whether or not object was found in tree

        return 0;
}

void buildTree(BinTree& T, ifstream& infile)
{
        string s;

        for (;;)
        {
                infile >> s;
                cout << s << ' ';
                if (s == "$$") break;
                if (infile.eof()) break;

                NodeData* ptr = new NodeData(s);

                bool success = T.insert(ptr);
                if (!success)
                        delete ptr;
        }
}
```

thanks

```
    valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./a.out
==2201== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==2201== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==2201== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==2201== Command: ./a.out
==2201== 
initial data:
 iii not tttt eee r not and jj r eee pp r sssss eee not tttt ooo ff m m y z $$ 
==2201== 
==2201== HEAP SUMMARY:
==2201==     in use at exit: 72,960 bytes in 9 blocks
==2201==   total heap usage: 40 allocs, 31 frees, 83,512 bytes allocated
==2201== 
==2201== 256 bytes in 8 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==2201==    at 0x4C2A0FC: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2201==    by 0x401820: buildTree(BinTree&, std::basic_ifstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&) (new.cpp:187)
==2201==    by 0x401718: main (new.cpp:168)
==2201== 
==2201== 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 2
==2201==    at 0x4C29BBE: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==2201==    by 0x4EC0A1F: pool (eh_alloc.cc:123)
==2201==    by 0x4EC0A1F: __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (eh_alloc.cc:250)
==2201==    by 0x4EC0A1F: _GLOBAL__sub_I_eh_alloc.cc (eh_alloc.cc:326)
==2201==    by 0x400F4F9: call_init.part.0 (in /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so)
==2201==    by 0x400F60A: _dl_init (in /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so)
==2201==    by 0x4000DA9: ??? (in /usr/lib/ld-2.24.so)
==2201== 
==2201== LEAK SUMMARY:
==2201==    definitely lost: 256 bytes in 8 blocks
==2201==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2201==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2201==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
==2201==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==2201== 
==2201== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==2201== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Can you please include the Valgrind output? And you are running a debug build? I.e. you have the `-g` flag when building? And not stripping the executable file from debug information?

Comment: And maybe a main to test the problematic function?

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use `new` operator without a `std::unique_ptr` and then you'll not have this problem at all... Do you have a particular reason why have to manage memory yourself and not let a smart pointer do it for you? Here's a link about it: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr

Comment: By the way, you should really read about [the rules of three and five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Furthermore your copy-constructor is no better than the default compiler-generated copy-constructor and will not work if it ever will be used. The copy-constructor needs to do a *deep* copy, not just copy the pointer (which is what the compiler-generated assignment operator will do).

Comment: Furthermore, your `insertHelper` function should really return the result of the recursive calls.

Comment: i added the valgrind output after building with -g

Comment: Lastly, I don't see why `Node::data` needs to be a pointer? Or why you need a `NodeData` structure at all if the data is just a string? The less pointers you use, the less you have to worry about memory leaks.

Comment: What's `new.cpp` line 187?

Comment: line 187 is: NodeData* ptr = new NodeData(s);

Comment: In your `insertHelper` function, what happens when `*insertion == *current->data`? Think a little about that. Especially considering my previous comment about not returning what the recursive calls are returning.

Comment: *insertion == *current->data returns false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `insertHelper` code is broken because when it calls `insertHelper` recursively, it ignores the return value and returns `true` even if the object wasn't inserted, leading to a leak.

Instead of this:

```
    else if (*insertion < *current->data)
    {
            insertHelper(current->left, insertion);
    }
    else if (*insertion > *current->data)
    {
            insertHelper(current->right, insertion);
    }
```

You need this:

```
    else if (*insertion < *current->data)
    {
            return insertHelper(current->left, insertion);
    }
    else if (*insertion > *current->data)
    {
            return insertHelper(current->right, insertion);
    }
```

Why are you using naked pointers anyway?

Comment: I mean a pointer that isn't wrapped in some kind of logic to permit its lifetime to be intelligently managed, forcing you to manage it manually. (Which, as you can see, is easy to get wrong.)